# How do I validate the correct date format pattern? Format patterns, not dates from strings

Tags: java

I use Spring in my project and the property file looks like this.

```
reportPRM.field=\
TrxDateTime   |6    |yyMMdd;\
TrxDateTime   |6    |HHmmss;\
MerchantID    |16   |Space;\
```

I have one property with multiple lines. Users can change the date format pattern for TrxDateTime. I need to validate the correctness of the pattern. How to do it?

I have tried the code below.

```
public static boolean validatePattern(String template) {
    try {
        new SimpleDateFormat(template);

        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.error(ThrowableHelper.getMessage(e));
    }

    return false;
}
```

But it turns out to giving true for input "0".

Edit. Added unit test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "scheduler.enable=false")
public class DateFormatTest {

    @Test
    public void testDateFormat() {
        assertTrue(StringHelper.validatePattern("0"));
        assertTrue(StringHelper.validatePattern("abcde"));

        assertTrue(StringHelper.validatePattern("yyyyMMdd"));
        assertTrue(StringHelper.validatePattern("HHmmss"));
    }

}
```

For input "0", "yyyyMMdd", "HHmmss" returns `true` and for "abcde" returns `false`. But I don't think this is enough. Date format patterns must comply to general standard patterns.

Edit 2. This is the complete properties.

```
reportPRM.field=\
TrxDateTime                                     |6  |yyMMdd;\
TrxDateTime                                     |6  |HHmmss;\
MerchantID                                      |16 |Space;\
CompanyName                                     |25 |Space;\
                                                |2  |ID;\
CardNo                                          |19 |0;\
                                                |4  |CPAY;\
Amount                                          |15 |0;\
{P: RespDesc, R: RespDescReversal}              |6  |0;\
{P: DSPRetCodePayment, R: DSPRetCodeReversal}   |3  |0;
```

I need to iterate through each line and check if the value in column 3 is pattern for date format. But the function above gives `true` for "0".

Comment: Use `RegEx` to match input format.

Comment: @kozmo Not sure if that is good advise. The point is that ANYONE knowing the rules for patterns should be able to put down VALID patterns. Are you sure you know all valid rules, so you can write a regex that matches exactly those?!

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Where’s the limit? What exactly are your requirements? If users — hypothetically — want a `0` instead fo the date, you don’t want to allow that? How about only year or only month?

Comment: @OleV.V. I need to loop through each line of the `reportPRM.field` property and check If the value in third column (there are 3 columns for each row divided by "|") contains the pattern for the date time format then the specific format and parsing task will be done. My problem is the function above also treats "0" as a valid character.

Comment: I don’t think you understood my question. `0` works as a valid date format pattern string. `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("0"))` produces `0`. The empty string works too. You haven’t told us what your problem is.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, `0` works as a valid pattern string, but should not be allowed by the unit test. It's a fixed number of allowed patterns and a function to validate these. And for that you don't need DateTimeFormatter (or SimpleDateFormat) at all. You only need to make sure that all allowed patterns actually work as date format (unit test) and that the validate function returns the expected result (more unit tests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the `SimpleDateFormat` class and its friends like `Date`. Those classes were poorly designed and are now long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Your exact requirements are not clear. I present code for the following requirements. The *date* pattern should be a valid pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` and should contain at least one pattern letter for dates, for example `yyMMdd` or just `d`. Era (BC/AD) alone is not enough. Letters in single quotes do not count since they don’t work as pattern letters but as literals. The *time* pattern should similarly contain at least one pattern letter for time of day, not time zone, and fraction of second or nano of second is not enough.

For checking the validity the `try`/`catch` block you’ve got is fine. The only issue with it is that for example `0` works nicely as a valid pattern, but you want to reject it. So in addition I use a regular expression to check that at least one relevant pattern letter is present outside single quotes. The regular expression accepts any run of characters with an *even* number of single quotes before and after the letter.

```
private static final String DATE_PATTERN_LETTERS = "uyDMLdgQqYwWEecF";
private static final Pattern DATE_PATTERN_PATTERN = requireAtLeastOne(DATE_PATTERN_LETTERS);
private static final String TIME_PATTERN_LETTERS = "ahKkHmsAN";
private static final Pattern TIME_PATTERN_PATTERN = requireAtLeastOne(TIME_PATTERN_LETTERS);

/**
 * @return a pattern that matches a string that contains
 *          at least one of the letters in {@code requiredLetters} not within single quotes
 */
private static Pattern requireAtLeastOne(String requiredLetters) {
    return Pattern.compile("[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*[" + requiredLetters + "][^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*");
}

public static boolean validateDatePattern(String template) {
    if (! isValidPattern(template)) {
        return false;
    }
    return DATE_PATTERN_PATTERN.matcher(template).matches();
}

public static boolean validateTimePattern(String template) {
    if (! isValidPattern(template)) {
        return false;
    }
    return TIME_PATTERN_PATTERN.matcher(template).matches();
}

private static boolean isValidPattern(String template) {
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(template);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Let’s try it with some date patterns:

```
    System.out.println(validateDatePattern("0"));
    System.out.println(validateDatePattern("abcde"));
    System.out.println(validateDatePattern("yyyyMMdd"));
    System.out.println(validateDatePattern("HHmmss"));
    System.out.println(validateDatePattern("'yMd in quotes'"));
    System.out.println(validateDatePattern("yMd 'outside quotes'"));
```

Output is, with my comments:

```
false  // 0 fails because it doesn’t contain a pattern letters for a date
false  // abcde fails because b is not a valid pattern letter
true   // yyyyMMdd is fine
false  // HHmmss fails because it’s for times, not dates
false  // 'yMd in quotes' fails because yMd are in quotes
true   // yMd 'outside quotes' is fine
```

Let’s see a few time pattern strings too:

```
    System.out.println(validateTimePattern("0"));
    System.out.println(validateTimePattern("yyyyMMdd"));
    System.out.println(validateTimePattern("HHmmss"));
```

Output:

```
false
false
true
```

> Can you give a brief explanation of the regex you provided?

Sure. `[^']*` matches 0 or more characters that are not `'` (single quote). Next `(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*` matches 0 or more sequences where each sequence is one single quote, 0 or more non-single-quotes, one single quote and 0 or more non-single-quotes. This makes sure that there is an even number of single quotes (and since they come in pairs, this in turn makes sure that the following pattern letter is not within single quotes). It also matches no single quotes at all since there may be 0 such sequences. Next I put the required letters inside `[` and `]` to require just one of them. Finally I repeat `[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*`, the same as before the letter.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation of the regex you provided?

Answer (score 2):

The [SimpleDateFormat API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)) says:

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings. Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote. **All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during formatting or matched against the input string during parsing.**
>
> The following pattern letters are defined (**all other characters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are reserved**):

(bold by me)

So if you only want to allow date and time pattern letters in your input String, then build a Regex containing the letters you want to allow (as subset of [A-Za-z] of the defined pattern table given in above link) and match the input String against the Regex as kosmo already pointed out.

To allow your two defined formats, you would need Regex `yyMMdd|HHmmss` for an exact match or `[msdyHM]+` if you allow all those letters in any combination.

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] patterns = { "[msdyHM]+", "yyMMdd|HHmmss" };
        String[] input = { "yyMMdd", "HHmmss", "yyyyMMdd", "0", "mm", "abcd" };
        for (String pattern : patterns) {
            for (String str : input) {
                System.out.println(pattern + " match " + str + " " + str.matches(pattern) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[msdyHM]+ match yyMMdd true
[msdyHM]+ match HHmmss true
[msdyHM]+ match yyyyMMdd true
[msdyHM]+ match 0 false
[msdyHM]+ match mm true
[msdyHM]+ match abcd false
yyMMdd|HHmmss match yyMMdd true
yyMMdd|HHmmss match HHmmss true
yyMMdd|HHmmss match yyyyMMdd false
yyMMdd|HHmmss match 0 false
yyMMdd|HHmmss match mm false
yyMMdd|HHmmss match abcd false
```

Comment: For some reason `SimpleDateFormat` also treats characters other than `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z` as the correct pattern.

Comment: Other characters are just copied. Example: `new SimpleDateFormat("0123@dd-MM").format(new Date())` outputs "0123@28-02" just like `"'0123@'dd'-'MM"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [format symbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you probably want to offer just a subset - too much may go wrong - undetected.

- HH = 24 hours, hh = 12 hours (which differs PM)
- yyyy = year. YYYY = week year (which differs when the week overlaps two years)

And too many patterns are acceptable to a date time formatter.

This means some measure/effort:

- Ideally provide a GUI to create the pattern (i.e. with a combobox Hours with 12 | 24).
- Provide a cheat sheet.
- Allow some patterns, hh only when followed by a (AM/PM); provide a hotline e-mail.
- Have a white list of patterns.
- Go with your custom pattern; take for instance Excel .xlsx patterns, and convert them to java patterns.